# Animation preview lagging

Tags: animation, 3d-view, frame-rate

I just downloaded blender and I'm starting with this whole world. The thing is I have a little project for college where basically I'm doing a box with courtains inside, a back door and a water container on the side. Whenever I press the play button below the scene is really lagging, the fps are in red and display 6~7 fps. Like I said, I'm new so is this an error due to a missconfiguration from my part? Is my graphics card not enough or not properly configured? Are my onjects too many for the scene? Because with one cube moving around it seems to be just fine. Is this preview how my actual project is going to be? I would really appreciate some help :)

I have an Intel core i7-6700 CPU @ 3.40GHz 3.40 GHz, 8GB of RAM, NVIDIA GeForce GT 730 and Blender v2.83.0

Answer (score 0):

Animation is laggy in the viewport the first time you run it. It will be at the desired framerate once you render. Also, remember to set your output to video so you don't have to put together an image sequence.

~Dan